# What exactly is the difference between under the sea and in the sea?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I know that "under the sea" means someone is under the sea surface, which is equivalent to being submerged under water. If that's the case, are there any differences between "in the sea" and "under the sea"?

For example, a person is scuba diving. What is the difference between:

> He is scuba diving under the sea

and

> He is scuba diving in the sea

Another example:

> The fish is in the sea

and

> The fish is under the sea

One more example:

> The submarine is under the sea

and

> The submarine is in the sea

Answer (score 2):

The only real difference is that someone swimming on the surface of the ocean is still *in* the sea, but they aren't *under* the sea.

Comment: And a boat on the surface of the ocean can be said to be _at sea._

Answer (score 0):

Normally we use **under the sea** to refer to a great depth.

> The bathysphere revolutionized the study of deep sea creatures. It could submerge to great depths, enabling scientists to  view life under the sea.